# Changing the color of a substring

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

The following code changes the color of part of the string in a cell (in A1 I have the text "tur a, bs a", where "tur" and "bs" is in bold).

```vb
Range("A1").Characters(Start:=8, Length:=2).Font.Color = vbRed
```

I want "bs" to appear in red:
[image]

The code changes the format of the text as shown:
[image]

With the following code,

```vb
Range("A1").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font.Color = vbRed
```

the text "tur" is correctly shown in red:
[image]

Maybe this behavior is specific to the MacOS version?

Answer (score 0):

Very curious indeed. I'm on Windows and get the same result. I can get the desired result by combining everything in one `With` statement, but I'm not sure if this is an option for you. Like this:

```
Sub test()

With Range("A1")
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Characters(8, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Characters(1, 3).Font.Bold = True
    .Characters(8, 2).Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

The order for setting the color and weight doesn't seem to matter. But even now you might notice that Excel has difficulty with this. E.g. above, I've used `.Font.Bold = False` and `.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)` to "reset" the weight and color beforehand. Normally, I would just use `.ClearFormats`. However, if I have a string like your "**tur** a, **bs** a", and try to clear the formats, it will actually keep "**bs**" in bold (but not "tur") and repeating the clear formats command changes nothing.

Very strange...

---

Update: Global solution. I've made a function that puts current formats for each char in an array. Next, it changes the entries that need updating and returns the new arr. Use in the sub and then update the formats one char at a time in a loop. This worked on examples that got messed up otherwise. Code:

```
Sub updateFormats()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    'ref to appropriate cell address
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    
    'call updateFormats, e.g. for pos = 8, length = 2, type = "Color", typeValue = vbRed:
    arr = arrNewFormats(rng, 8, 2, "Color", vbRed)

    'Example for "Bold":
    'arr = arrNewFormats(rng, 3, 2, "Bold", True)

    'reassign formats per char
    For i = 1 To Len(rng)
        rng.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Color = arr(i, 1)
        rng.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Bold = arr(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    
End Sub

Function arrNewFormats(rng As Range, startPos As Long, myLength As Long, myType As String, myTypeValue)

    'myType: either "Color" or "Bold"
    'myTypeValue:   for "Color", e.g. vbRed, or RGB(255,0,0) (N.B. not "vbRed" or "RGB(255,0,0) )
    '               for "Bold", True or False

    Dim chars As Characters
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim n As Long, types As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    n = Len(rng)
    types = 2 'for "color" and "bold"
    
    'populate arr with current types
    ReDim arr(1 To n, 1 To types)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    
        'get character
        Set chars = rng.Characters(i, 1)
        'assign "color" and "bold"
        arr(i, 1) = chars.Font.Color
        arr(i, 2) = chars.Font.Bold

    Next i

    'Choosing type
    If myType = "Color" Then
        j = 1
    ElseIf myType = "Bold" Then
        j = 2
    End If
    
    'Update formats
    For i = 0 To myLength - 1
        arr(startPos + i, j) = myTypeValue
    Next i
    
    'return updated arr
    arrNewFormats = arr

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is not an option for me because in my use case the positions of the text to put in red are not fixed (they depend on values in other cells) and I do not know in advance the format of the rest of the text, that I want to keep. As a first step towards a potential global solution, I tried with `.Characters(1, 3).Font.Bold = Range("A1").Characters(1, 3).Font.Bold` to keep the format of characters 1-3, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Updated solution might work as a more global solution. Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! The only minor issue is that it is much slower than the original (non-working) simple solution, as characters are traversed one by one.